# Top 1 without ordering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I encountered a problem with query result. The result wasn't same on the live environment and the test environment.

Table A

```
id, name
1,ValueA1
```

Table B

```
Id, name
1,ValueB1
2,ValueB2
3,ValueB3
4,ValueB4
```

On the test environment the result was ValueB1, on the live environment was ValueB2

After the quick investigation I found that the problem is that the procedure was using `top 1` without ordering in conjunction. Ok, this is clear for everybody that if we have conjunction we have to add order by clause if we use top 1.

But I tried to explain the problem to a not technical person.

So I wrote a simple while loop with a 1 000 000 iteration. Inside I clear execution plans:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

and

```
sp_recompile 'ProcedureName'
```

and next I was executing procedure.

Unfortunately the result was always the same. On the both environments. (on the test: ValueB1, on the live: ValueB2)

I tried changing calling procedure to just copy the content of the procedure.
The results still exactly same as in previous case.

I tried to write a very simple conjunction query with top 1 without ordering. the result that time was same on both servers: ValueB1 in all 1M iterations.

The db procedure is pretty complicated it use CTE and it join to the table B multiple times.

I am very frustrated that I didn't manage to show the problem to the non technical person.

Can anyone explain what I did wrong or how it should have been done?

Comment: What is your question here? Why aren't you getting the same answer in all environments?

Comment: The problem might be because you are using different databases on test environment and production environment. If I am correct, the order of data (without any sorting, that is in physical files) must be different in test and production environment.

Comment: Data order is never guaranteed without `ORDER BY`. Period

Comment: Without a specified order the result is arbitrary, the DBMS is free to deliver the result in the order that it finds suitable. One possible reason for the behavior you see is the way data is physically stored on disk, it just happens to be most convenient to return a particular row in dev, and another in prod. If you physically change the data (reorganize it one way or another) the results may change.

Comment: See if pointing this person to this article helps. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx My question is why do you need to explain this to a non-technical person? If this person wants the data in a certain order then you need to tell them that there is a bug and the order will not be guaranteed unless you fix the bug. What do you mean by a "conjunction query"? You mentioned that twice in your post and I have never heard that before.

Comment: Hi guys, I asked to read the whole post. I know that order by is neccessary in conjunction. It's clear for me, if for someone not go to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Comment: Hi Lennart, primary keys for both tables are set on ID columns. So if clustered index (primary key) is set on ID on the both servers data should be physically stored in the same way.

Comment: My question is: How to write a loop which use  TOP in conjunction without the ORDER BY clause, and will return me a different results. I thought that i cannot achieved this because SQL Server saves execution plans. So I tried to clear them. But I still haven't received a result i want.

Comment: In https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx
I can read "When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order"
I would like to write a loop which will prove this "undefined order"
The output I am after is that in each iteration of the loop order of the result will be different.

Comment: if you really want to continue down this path (despite the comments of others), you could try looking at the query plans generated in your live and test environments. Differences in the query plans may give you some more insight into what might have caused the differences in ordering, and what events may have taken place to cause this (e.g. different parameter sniffing on live and test).

Comment: Without using an "Order By" clause I believe the "TOP 1" will return based on how the data is stored.  Depending on how the data was inserted and how the Primary Key is setup, you may return different data.  I would suggest rebuilding the index or create a test table with no index whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you don't specify an order by clause the engine is free to deliver the result to you as it sees fit.

In practice that mostly means its ordered by the clustered index, but it don't have to be!